# Nuclide with React Native - Runtime is not ready for debugging

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native, nuclide-editor

Trying to use nuclide with atom but I cannot get the debugger to work. I have nuclide installed (v0.126.0). Running on Mac and followed the setup instructions in the docs. I run the RN packager within Nuclide, start the debugger and then run 'react-native run-ios' from terminal and lastly enable chrome debugging. I get this error as if the packager or chrome are not running.

[image: Simulator Error]
[image]
If I click on the cog on the debugger I get this output which I can't make sense out of
[image]

If I close the debugger within nuclide it runs fine within normal Chrome debugging. Any help would be appreciated, lost at this point

Comment: is your chrome pointed to debugging url when you run debugger in nuclide?

Comment: @BilalBudhani Thanks for the reply! No I have tried with Chrome not running and with Chrome open on a blank tab only

Comment: Pretty much giving up on Nuclide, another person on my team couldn't get it to run either